# injecting strings in json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In java script I create a json var

```
var Token = { "TagItem": { "TagList": [tags] } };
```

where tags is

```
"AA","BB","CCC","DDDD"
```

I call an asp mvc controller using ajax and I send the json to a method.
the desirialized json object is

```
public class TagItem
{
   public List<string> TagList { get; set; }
}
```

and it is deserialized in ajax call to list with a single value of ["AA","BB","CCC","DDDD"].
instead of many values as if I would have writted

```
var data = { "tagItem": { "TagList": ["AA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD"]} };
```

Which works great.

Idea on how to write it in js?

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand this at all!  What's your question?  What are you trying to do here?  `["AA","BB","CCC","DDDD"]` is an array, with multiple values in it.  Is that not what you wanted?  What is `public List<string> TagList`?  That's not JavaScript code!  This question makes no sense.

Comment: `var data = { "tagItem": { "TagList": ["AA", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD"]} };` - this is js. You've already written it. PS: it's not JSON, it's a javascript object

Comment: What *exactly* is `tags`?  How *exactly* are you calling that controller?

Comment: No, but I have it as a variable var Token = { "TagItem": { "TagList": [tags] } };. which doesn't desirialize

Comment: @rails: Your `TagList` is an array of one element, `tags`.  `[tags]` creates an array with one element in it.  What does `tags` contain?  Don't tell me that `tags` is a string containing commas.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: sadly it is a string containing commas. very noob in js . My question title is "injecting strings in json". is it possible?

Comment: @rails: That's what I figured the issue was.  You can't do `[tags]` and expect it to magically turn into an array.  What you want is `tags.split(',')`.  That will turn it into an array!

Comment: @rails: How are you generating `tags`? Can you control that, or no? If so, you may be able to add them one-by-one to an array, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`[tags]` will create an array with only one element, tags.</strike>

If `tags` is a comma separated string like `"AA,BB,CCC,DDDD"`, then you can use `.split` to transform it into an array.

```
var Token = { "TagItem": { "TagList": tags.split(',') } };
```

**UPDATE**: After seeing the screenshot you posted (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI32C.png), I see what the real error  here is.  It's how you are creating `tags`.

You don't need to add `"`, or `,`.  You are just building an array/an object, you are not building a string.  `.map` returns you an array, no need to convert it a string using `.join`, just use it as an array.

```
var tags = $('#myTags input[name="tags"]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

var Token = { "TagItem": { "TagList": tags } };
```

Note: There are no `[]` around `tags`.  That's because it's *already* an array, no need to add it to another array.

Comment: Nope. This has the same result. 1 item in list.

Comment: @rails: What *exactly* is `tags`?  What does `console.log(tags)` and `console.log(tags.split(','))` show?

Comment: @rails: I see a lot of issues with your code from this screenshot.

Comment: @rails: When you're doing `$('#myTags input[name="tags"]').map`, why are you adding quotes around the string?  Also, why are you using `.join(',')`?  Just have the map function `return $(this).val()`, and don't use `.join`, just use `tags` as an array.  `var tags = $('#myTags input[name="tags"]').map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();  var Token = { "TagItem": { "TagList": tags } };`  You are building a JavaScript object, *not* a JSON string, you don't need to add `"`s.